# Conditional formatting export to html

Tags: html, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, ms-access-2007

I'm working on a database which creates a report, with two subreports. One is in the detail section of the main form, and the second is in the footer section of the main form.

The first subreport uses four conditional formatting rules, based on fields in the detail of the subreport.

The main report needs to be exported to html, so that it can be sent out as an email. The problem is, the conditional formatting doesn't carry over, when exported to html.

It's important that the email actually contain the report, and not an attachment.

It would also be best if the whole process could be done automatically, with VBA.

Currently, the code produces an email, with no conditional formatting, so I just need help with getting the formatting onto the HTML file.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not going to be easy. Here is one option - report to PDF to HTML: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21166689/Access-report-export-colors-lost-in-HTML-and-Word.html

Comment: Or, if "regular" static formatting does get exported to HTML, replace the conditional formatting by VBA code in the `OnFormat` events of the report sections.

Comment: Andre, thanks for the reply. I've looked at the PDF>HTML option, but I couldn't get it to work, without a lot of manual intervention. I've also tried the OnFormat event, but it always just formats all rows, as opposed to formatting each row independently.